# Short story about ruining civil society

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, dystopia

Please help me identify an old short story.

Civil society is dystopic and getting worse. Narrator describes recent crime, violence, and mayhem. Bad news, right?

Nope. Two apparent beat cops, the narrator and a coworker, are comparing their status reports. Society is declining roughly according to plan.

Narrator finishes up by shaking his head, saying something like "grannies with shotguns blowing people away just ain't right."

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Do you recall where (magazine, anthology, online)?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because as written, this does not appear to be about science fiction or fantasy.

Comment: @Lexible that seems a little harsh as it's clearly a dystopia. Your logic would make Fahrenheit 451 not science fiction.

Comment: @JohnRennie It sounds like the daily news. Not sure where you are getting "harsh".

Comment: @Lexible OP says it's an old story. "Society is declining roughly according to plan" is everyday reality in 2023, but it could have been futuristic dystopia when it was written.

Comment: Hi @Lexible. Mosdef written by a predominately sci-fi author. I somehow have Arthur C. Clark stuck in my head. But haven't been able to refind it on my own. FWIW, some of those early authors didn't distinguish between their own fiction and sci-fi work, so who am I to judge?

Comment: Hi @DavidW, IIRC from a soft-bound anthology of '60s sci-fi. We used to just pass them along. Might have been of just a single author. Not much more than that quote about grannies to go on, Sorry. I just keep thinking of how prescient the story was and can't let it go.